# How to add a marker after initialization in javascript

Tags: javascript, maps, initialization, marker

I created the following code to show a Map

```
<script>
var myLatlng;
var mapOptions;
var map;
var marker;

function initialize() {
   myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
   mapOptions = {zoom: 4,center: myLatlng,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

// marker 1
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng, map: map,title: 'Hello World!'});

// marker 2
   myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-24.363882,131.044922);
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng, map: map,title: 'Hello Ciccio!'});

// marker 3
   myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-20.363882,131.044922);
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng, map: map,title: 'Hello Pippo!'});
}

function writeMap(){
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}

function addMarker(){
// marker 4
   myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-18.363882,131.044922);
   marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatlng, map: map,title: 'Hello PLUTO!'});

}

</script>
```

If I invoke addMarker() in the initialize function that works, if I try to call the function within the HTML code it doesn't.

How can I create a Marker after the initialize function has been executed?

Thanks.
Enrico

Comment: a) How are you calling the function from within the html-code? b) Have you tried the addMarker() from a console?

Comment: If I do that from the console it works! this is the HTML code:
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <script> 
 writeMap();
 addMarker();
 // google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: Some more info: if I use the setTimeout function it works: `code`(setTimeout(function(){fullyLoaded()},500);)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the code itself, it's how you execute it. HTML does not execute anything, it's only a structure. In order for some code to be executed it has to be called, usually by binding it to an event. Putting things into  tags does not help here, it's only for definitions

Try adding a button with the attribute

```
<button onclick="addMarker()">
```

Comment: Thanks, but if the addMarker function contains just window.alert('HelloWorld'); that statement gets executed, I don't get why it does not execute the code to add Markers in the Map.

Comment: The workaround I found is the following: to automatically add Markers outside the initialize function I have to embed the call of the function into a setTimeout function.

See the example below:

setTimeout(function(){addMarker()},500);